# Printing Contents of arguments in Mason

Tags: perl, mason

I have a mason file which accepts arguments

```
<%args>
  $data
</%args>
```

When I use `FLLogError` to print `$data` it prints `HASH(0x853e6654)`.

Is there a way to print the contents of this hash so that I can verify that it is getting the required parameters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
use Data::Dumper;
FLLogError(Dumper $data);
```

or if you want all the args:

```
use Data::Dumper;
FLLogError(Dumper \%ARGS);
```

Comment: Dumper has to be written twice or once?

Comment: exactly as you see

Comment: I get an error: 'require' trapped by operation mask at

Comment: the error comes on the line where I wrote use Data::Dumper;  I am still getting it

Comment: resolved it. I just had to remove use Data::Dumper line! :D